# How to divide a 2D list into one 2D list and one array (remove the last column)

Tags: python, linear-regression

I have the following 2D list

```
list = [[1,1,a],[2,2,b],[3,3,c]]
```

and I want to convert this 2D list to one 2D list and an array

```
sublist = [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]] 
subarray = [a,b,c]
```

Is there any convenient way to do that in python. I'm new to python, so I dont know if there's any grammar which can perform the above calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List comprehensions are a good, clean solution:

```
sublist = [[a[0], a[1]] for a in list]
subarray = [a[2] for a in list]
```

Comment: invalid syntax at "from"

Comment: @user2744486 That's my bad; it should be `for`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
lst = [[1,1,a],[2,2,b],[1,3,c]]
sublist = list(map(lambda x: [x[0],x[1]], lst))
subarray = list(map(lambda x: x[2], lst))
```

Comment: What is the last variable "Ist"? python doesn't recognize this variable.

Comment: Second line should be `x[2]`, not `x[3]`, I believe

Comment: Thanks. Also I use lst instead of list because list is also a function (to cast something into a list...as I did)